# Space efficient combination of three graphs with common x-axis in Stata

Tags: stata

I am looking for something like the following `by()` graph, but instead of three panels for three groups, I want three panels with three different y variables.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
keep if inrange(company, 1, 3)
twoway line mvalue year, by(company, cols(1) compact)
```

I like the compactness and one common x-axis for all three panels. Can I this with different y variables?

I can combine the following three panels with `graph combine`. But this duplicates the x-axis and wastes a lot of space that could be better spent on y range.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
keep if (company == 1)
tsline mvalue, name(mvalue, replace)
tsline kstock, name(kstock, replace)
tsline invest, name(invest, replace)
graph combine mvalue kstock invest, cols(1) name(combined, replace)
```

I started stripping away x-axis titles and labels, but this affects the relative sizes of each panel. Is there a more straightforward solution here?

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
keep if (company == 1)
tsline mvalue, name(mvalue, replace) xtitle("") xlabel(none)
tsline kstock, name(kstock, replace) xtitle("") xlabel(none)
tsline invest, name(invest, replace)
graph combine mvalue kstock invest, cols(1) name(combined, replace)
```

Comment: See now also http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1355560-plotting-multiple-time-series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
keep if (company == 1)
tsline mvalue, name(mvalue, replace) xscale(off)
tsline kstock, name(kstock, replace) xscale(off)
tsline invest, name(invest, replace) 
graph combine mvalue kstock invest, cols(1) name(combined, replace) xcommon imargin(b=1 t=1)
```

The `xscale(off)` option suppresses the x-axis, and the `imargin()` cuts down the space at the top and bottom of each graph to make them smaller, and `xcommon` makes the scale the same.

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Documentation is always a lot more helpful once I know the answer! :)

Comment: @RichardHerron I would strongly urge you to get a copy of [VGSG](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/visual-guide-to-stata-graphics/). As much as I love Diderotesque ambitions of Stata documentation, VGSG is a much easier way to get Stata to do what you have in mind quickly when it comes to graphs.

Comment: Sold! Stata's documentation is _so good_, but I get overwhlemed when it comes to graphics. Thanks for the tip/link ($20 cheaper from Stata than from Amazon).

Comment: These panels are still not even. Has someone come up with a solution (other than reshaping)  since this post? This would be very useful.

Comment: @Susan What does "panels are still not even" mean?

Comment: I mean that the height of the invest is still not equal to the height of kstock and mvalue.

Comment: @Susan The height (as in the length of the y-axis) is the same. Only the scale was meant to be the same. If you want the range to be the same, just add the `ycommon` option. But then it makes sense to plot the three lines on the same chart. If that's not what you want, please start a new question where you spell our what you have in mind more clearly, perhaps using my code as the baseline. Feel free to tag me and I will take a look when I get some time.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program `sparkline` primarily motivated by display of multiple time series.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
set scheme s1color 
ssc inst sparkline 
sparkline invest mvalue kstock year if company == 1
```

[image]

Comment: Mine is even an example from the `sparkline` help file! :) Do you have any tips for discovering packages? Is there anything like R's task views? https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ Thanks!

Comment: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/graphics/gph/stata-graphs/  http://www.surveydesign.com.au/tipsgraphs.html http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/graph/njcplot.htmI may help.

Answer (score 0):

A third approach is to `reshape long` data, then use variable labels in `by()`.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
keep if (company == 1)

keep year mvalue kstock invest
foreach v of varlist mvalue kstock invest {
    rename `v' value`v'
}
reshape long value, i(year) j(var) string

label define var 1 "mvalue" 2 "kstock" 3 "invest"
rename var var0
encode var0, generate(var) label(var)
xtset var year
tsline value, by(var, cols(1))
```

[image]